# Get email address from phone number in Android

Tags: android, cursor, uri

I'm attempting to find someone's email address, given their phone number (assuming they have it stored in Contacts).

At the moment I've been fine if I want the person's name, or something, just doing:

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
            Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);
```

However, there is no way to search using a phone number, through the email DB

```
Uri emailUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI,
            Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(emailUri, null, null, null, null);
//Returns nothing, unless someone has the email +441234567891@hotmail.com or something
```

Now I could use CONTENT_FILTER_URI, and search for the name of the person I just found... But then I could get 2 John Smiths... There must be some way to just join across the PhoneLookup and the Email DBs? Maybe using the LOOKUP_KEY, or something?